# Is it safe to change variables after using glUniform pointer variants?

Tags: opengl

I'm wondering if glUniformXXv blocks until the data the pointer is referering to is copied to GPU. In other words, can this code cause issues if the GPU is busy?

```
int i=5;
glUniform1iv(location,1,&i);
i = 6;
```

Will this cause glUniform1fv to send 6 if the GPU is busy?

Comment: My mistake. I meant to write glUniform1fv .. sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the exception of OpenGL functions that end in the word "Pointer", *every* OpenGL function that takes a pointer will read from/write to that pointer before it returns. So changes to the memory after the fact will not be seen.